# CountVectorizer ignoring 'I'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Why is CountVectorizer in sklearn ignoring the pronoun "I"?

```
ngram_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer = "word", ngram_range = (2,2), min_df = 1)
ngram_vectorizer.fit_transform(['HE GAVE IT TO I'])
<1x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
ngram_vectorizer.get_feature_names()
['gave it', 'he gave', 'it to']
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The default tokenizer considers only 2-character (or more) words.

You can change this behaviour by passing an appropriate `token_pattern` to your `CountVectorizer`.

The default pattern is (see [the signature in the docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html)):

```
'token_pattern': u'(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b'
```

You can get a `CountVectorizer` that does not drop one-letter words by changing the default, for instance:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
ngram_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer="word", ngram_range=(2,2), 
                                   token_pattern=u"(?u)\\b\\w+\\b",min_df=1)
ngram_vectorizer.fit_transform(['HE GAVE IT TO I'])
print(ngram_vectorizer.get_feature_names())
```

Which gives:

```
['gave it', 'he gave', 'it to', 'to i']
```